# Existence of specific unitary transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Given vectors  $v_{1}, v_{2},\dots,v_{k}$ and $w_{1}, w_{2},\dots, w_{k}$ which satisfy condition $\forall i, j \in \{1,\dots,k\}$, $v_{i}\cdot v_{j} = w_{i}\cdot w_{j}$ (dot product), prove that there exist such unitary transformation $U$ such that that $U(v_{i})=w_{i}$.

I can pretty much see what's going on here. These two sets of vectors are just rotated, so this tells me that there must be some kind of isometry that rotates them, but this is just intuition.

Comment: Do you have a specific vector space you're working with?

Comment: Not really. I think it's enough to suppose that the vector space they are coming from is something like sp(V) + sp(W). (where V = {v1,...,vk}, W = {w1,...,wk}.

Actually i found answer to this question right here:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/583397/unitary-map-between-sets-of-vectors

Comment: Yes there you have it. I was having trouble proving this without that condition :P

Comment: I just made this excercise without using orthogonal complements, it was enough for me to prove one simple lemma (which is pretty obvious).